# I try to access arrays from struct in matlab

Tags: matlab

```
function myScript()

mat_files = dir('*.mat');
profiles = [];
sub_ints = {};
sub_bands = {};
for i = 1: numel(mat_files)
file_name = mat_files(i).name;
fprintf('processing %s\n', file_name);
data = load(file_name);
profiles = [profiles; data.profile];
sub_ints = [sub_ints; data.subints];
sub_bands = [sub_bands; data.subbands]; 
end

save('alldata.mat', 'profiles', 'sub_ints', 'sub_bands', '-v7.3');
end
```

But have the folowing error
Reference to non-existent field 'profile'.

> Error in myScript (line 13)
>   profiles =cell2mat ({profiles; data.profile}); 
>   profile is 1*64 double sub_ints is 18*64 double sub_bands is 16*64 double

Comment: Can you post what you get if you type  `disp(data)`?

Comment: Undefined function or variable 'data'.

Error in myScript (line 12)
    disp(data) = load(file_name);

Comment: Sorry, I meant type `disp(data)` in the command window AFTER you run your script, or after you run `data = load(file_name);`

Comment: The error message does not match your code

Comment: Do you have two files called `myScript` by any chance? Adiel is right, the error message doesn't match the code you have posted. What do you get if you comment all the content of the script out, and replaces it with `disp('Hello')`?

Comment: @Adiel, StewieGriffin, OP changed his code to `disp(data) = load(file_name);` and the error message changed, so Matlab is executing the correct script

Answer (score 0):

Check the type of array that you created when defining `sub_ints` and `sub_bands`. These are cell arrays so you need to use them differently. You might want to do the same with `profiles`.

```
for i = 1: numel(mat_files)
    file_name = mat_files(i).name;
    fprintf('processing %s\n', file_name);
    data = load(file_name);
    profiles = [profiles; data.profile];
    sub_ints{i} = data.subints;
    sub_bands{i} = data.subbands;
end

sub_ints = cell2mat(sub_ints);
sub_bands = cell2mat(sub_bands);
```

Comment: Then you need to check the content/type of data and data.profile, like Zep suggested. But you will need to implement my suggestion anyways.